# How to view backup Postgresql database in Postgresql Studio

Tags: django, heroku, postgresql-9.1

I have just backup Postgresql database , I would like to view it with Postgresql studio? I have searched on Internet but found no tutorial. Please give me some keywords or a link so I could read more about how to view it. 
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I've recently started using PostgreSQL, but not with PostgreSQL Studio, so my answer will be more of suggestion to hopefully get you started:

It seems to me that you would need to recreate and serve the database, and then connect to it via PostgreSQL Studio. If I were to do this from scratch, from, say, Fedora, and use **[pgadmin](https://www.pgadmin.org)** instead of PostgreSQL Studio, these are the basic steps I would take (assuming you have a 'proper' postgresql backup file):

```
 # 1. Install PostgreSQL:

    dnf install postgresql, postgresql-contrib, postgresql-server

 # 2. Init db and data directory

    sudo postgresql-setup initdb

 # 3. Start PostgreSQL

    sudo systemctl start postgresql

 # 4. Create yourself as a superuser

    createuser <you> -s

 # 5. Launch psql

    psql

 # 6. Restore database (you might need to createdb first)

    dbname < postgres_backup_file;

 # 7. Exit

    \q
```

After this, launch PostgreSQL Studio and connect to the database.
See the bottom of this page for instructions on connecting: [http://www.postgresqlstudio.org/support/documentation/supportdocumentationinstallation-guide/](https://www.pgadmin.org)

The steps above are minimal, and there are many places where things can get sticky and frustrating. My best resource, besides Google, for resolving issues, was the source itself:
[https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/index.html][2]

Also, if you don't already have PostgreSQL Studio running, then that is another potential problem area, and I would suggest using pgadmin locally or psql itself. Psql will allow you to use regular SQL queries to explore the db without the hassle of installing any guis.